# How to change the visibility of specific elements using the display attribute (html/php)

Tags: html, css, html-table, visibility

Disclaimer: This is a code segment, not the source in its entirety.

So currently I have a large table enveloping individual tables for a given day (Monday/Tuesday). For each day there's a dropdown box that is supposed to generate large and small text boxes, and that part works (as evidenced in the Tuesday portion).

The part I'm having problems with is trying to change the visibility of anything else, whether it's an h2 element, a td element or even just the tbody element (I believe the default display values for each of those are "block", "table-row" and "table-row-group" respectively).

The error I've been getting in Chrome's source console is that no matter what type the element is (except for text boxes), it says that its undefined, even though the text boxes have their names and ids displayed in the exact same way.

Please let me know if you understand why this is happening.

[image: Problem]

[image: Segment]

Note: the particular element that I'm working with at the moment is "mondayWork" in the monday section.

```
                <table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="2" width="500">
                    <tbody>

                        <!--Name text box-->
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left">First and Last Name</td>
                            <td align="left">
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <!--Email text box-->
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left">Email Address</td>
                            <td align="left">
                                <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <!--Date calendar (user chooses first monday of the week-->
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left">Date</td>
                            <td align="left">
                                <input type="date" onchange=name="date" id="date">
                            </td>
                        </tr>       

                        <script>
                        $('dates').show();
                        </script>

                        <div id="dates">

                        <!--Shift Drop Down Box (Monday)-->
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th align="left">Monday (Date)</th>
                                    <th align="left">
                                        <select name="mondayShift" id="mondayShift" 
                                        onchange=
                                        "if (this.value=='1' || this.value=='3' || this.value=='5' || this.value=='8' || this.value=='9' || this.value=='10' || this.value=='11' || this.value=='12'){
                                        this.form['ddSTBM'].style.display='none'
                                        this.form['mondayWork'].style.display='table-row-group'
                                        }
                                        if (this.value=='2' || this.value=='7'){
                                        this.form['ddSTBM'].style.display='none'
                                        this.form['mondayWork'].style.display='none'
                                        }
                                        if (this.value=='4' || this.value=='6'){
                                        this.form['ddSTBM'].style.display='inline'
                                        this.form['mondayWork'].style.display='none'
                                        }                                 
                                        ">    
                                            <option selected disabled hidden value=''></option>
                                            <option value="1">In Office</option><!--Generates large text box-->     
                                            <option value="2">Not Scheduled</option>          
                                            <option value="3">Worked Remotely</option><!--Generates large text box-->
                                            <option value="4">On Call (Not called in)</option><!--Generates small text box-->   
                                            <option value="5">On Call (Called in)</option><!--Generates large text box-->
                                            <option value="6">Holiday</option><!--Generates small text box--> 
                                            <option value="7">Unpaid Time Off-Approved</option>
                                            <option value="8">Unpaid Time Off-Extreme Circumstances</option><!--Generates large text box-->
                                            <option value="9">Sick</option><!--Generates large text box-->
                                            <option value="10">Suspended</option><!--Generates large text box-->
                                            <option value="11">No Show</option><!--Generates large text box-->
                                            <option value="12">No Call/No Show</option> <!--Generates large text box-->
                                        </select>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody name="mondayWork" id="mondayWork" style="display: none;">
                                <!--Dropdown Small Text Box (Monday)-->
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="left">
                                        <input type="text" name="ddSTBM" id="ddSTBM" style="display: none;">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <!--Dropdown Large Text Box (Monday)-->
                                <tr>
                                    <td name="tdM1" id="tdM1" align = "right">Tasks</td>
                                </tr>
                                    <!--name="hdrM1" id="hdrM1" align = "right" style="text-align:left; display: none;"-->

                                <tr>
                                    <td align = "right">
                                        <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="ddLTBM" id="ddLTBM">Explain what you did today here</textarea>
                                        </td>
                                </tr>

                                <!--Troubles Large Text Box-->
                                <tr>
                                    <td align = "left">
                                        <h2 name="hdrM2" id="hdrM2" style="text-align:left;">Troubles</h2>
                                        <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="ddLTBM2" id="ddLTBM2">Explain any issues that occurred here</textarea>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>       

                                <!--Improvement Large Text Box-->
                                <tr>
                                    <td align = "left">
                                        <h2 name="hdrM3" id="hdrM3" style="text-align:left;">Improvement</h2>
                                        <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="ddLTBM3" id="ddLTBM3">Explain what you want to do better here</textarea>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                        <!--Shift Drop Down Box (Tuesday)-->
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                                <th>Tuesday (Date)</th>
                                <th>
                                    <select name="tuesdayShift" id="tuesdayShift" 
                                    onchange=
                                    "if (this.value=='1' || this.value=='3' || this.value=='5' || this.value=='8' || this.value=='9' || this.value=='10' || this.value=='11' || this.value=='12'){
                                    this.form['ddSTBT'].style.display='none'
                                    this.form['ddLTBT'].style.display='inline'
                                    this.form['ddLTBT2'].style.display='inline'
                                    this.form['ddLTBT3'].style.display='inline'
                                    }
                                    if (this.value=='2' || this.value=='7'){
                                    this.form['ddSTBT'].style.display='none'
                                    this.form['ddLTBT'].style.display='none'
                                    this.form['ddLTBT2'].style.display='none'
                                    this.form['ddLTBT3'].style.display='none'
                                    }
                                    if (this.value=='4' || this.value=='6'){
                                    this.form['ddSTBT'].style.display='inline'
                                    this.form['ddLTBT'].style.display='none'
                                    this.form['ddLTBT2'].style.display='none'
                                    this.form['ddLTBT3'].style.display='none'
                                    }                                 
                                    ">    
                                        <option selected disabled hidden value=''></option>
                                        <option value="1">In Office</option><!--Generates large text box-->     
                                        <option value="2">Not Scheduled</option>          
                                        <option value="3">Worked Remotely</option><!--Generates large text box-->
                                        <option value="4">On Call (Not called in)</option><!--Generates small text box-->   
                                        <option value="5">On Call (Called in)</option><!--Generates large text box-->
                                        <option value="6">Holiday</option><!--Generates small text box--> 
                                        <option value="7">Unpaid Time Off-Approved</option>
                                        <option value="8">Unpaid Time Off-Extreme Circumstances</option><!--Generates large text box-->
                                        <option value="9">Sick</option><!--Generates large text box-->
                                        <option value="10">Suspended</option><!--Generates large text box-->
                                        <option value="11">No Show</option><!--Generates large text box-->
                                        <option value="12">No Call/No Show</option> <!--Generates large text box-->
                                    </select>
                                </th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <!--Dropdown Small Text Box (Tuesday)-->
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="left">
                                        <input type="text" name="ddSTBT" id="ddSTBT" style="display: none;">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <!--Dropdown Large Text Box (Tuesday)-->
                                <tr>
                                    <td align = "right">
                                        <h2 name="hdrT1" id="hdrT1" style="text-align:left;">Tasks</h2>
                                        <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="ddLTBT" id="ddLTBT" style="display: none;">Explain what you did today here</textarea>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <!--Troubles Large Text Box-->
                                <tr>
                                    <td align = "left">
                                        <h2 name="hdrT2" id="hdrT2" style="text-align:left; display: none;">Troubles</h2>
                                        <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="ddLTBT2" id="ddLTBT2" style="display: none;">Explain any issues that occurred here</textarea>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>       

                                <!--Improvement Large Text Box-->
                                <tr>
                                    <td align = "left">
                                        <h2 name="hdrT3" id="hdrT3" style="text-align:left; display: none;">Improvement</h2>
                                        <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="ddLTBT3" id="ddLTBT3" style="display: none;">Explain what you want to do better here</textarea>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

<!--Submit button-->
<tr>
    <td align = "left">
        <input type="submit" name="btn_submit" id="btn_submit" style="width:150px; height:40px; font:bold 15px Venetian" value="Submit Report" >
    </td>
</tr>

</div>

</tbody></table>
</form><br>
                    </body>
                    </html>";
    }
 }
 ?>
 <br class="clearfloat">

 Copyright &copy; <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 var today = new Date()
 var year = today.getFullYear()
 document.write(year)
 </script>
```

Comment: "it says that its undefined" - Can you clarify this statement? What code are you trying?

Comment: `$('dates')` Here, `dates` is not a selector unless you created an ad-hoc element like `<dates>`. You probably want `$('#dates')` or `$('.dates')` or something along those lines.

Comment: @wavemode I've attached a few pictures where the error comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is because `this.form['mondayWork']` not refer to element belonging to the form. `mondayWork` is belong in tbody tag and it's id attribute. To select this id you have to use document.getElementById

```
 document.getElementById('mondayWork').style.display = 'none'
```

Comment: OH MY GOD...GAHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH